# which new operator will be called new or new[]?

Tags: c++, new-operator

In the below program overloaded `operator new []` is getting called. But if I comment this function then my overloaded `operator new` is getting called. Shouldn't It called `default new []` operator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 

void *operator new (size_t os)
{
    cout<<"size : "<<os<<endl;
    void *t;
    t=malloc(os);
    if (t==NULL)
    {}
    return (t);
}

//! Comment This below function
void* operator new[](size_t size){
    void* p;
    cout << "In overloaded new[]" << endl;
    p = malloc(size);
    cout << "size :" << size << endl;
    if(!p){
    }
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void *ss) {free(ss);}

int main ()
{
    int *t=new int[10];
    delete t;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 interesting. [clang-3.5 does call it.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kDxBGkv2bLVBUkj3)

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed, [removing the `-O2` "fixes" it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12a030edc1905452)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), we see:

> 1. `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );`
>    Called by non-array new-expressions to allocate storage required for a single object. […]
> 2. `void* operator new[]( std::size_t count );`
>    Called by the array form of `new[]`-expressions to allocate all storage required for an array (including possible new-expression overhead). **The standard library implementation calls version (1)**

Thus, if you overload version (1) but do *not* overload version (2), your line

```
int *t = new int[10];
```

will call the standard library's `operator new []`.  But that, in turn calls `operator new(size_t)`, which you have overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is one difference between them. With "new" keyword, it just allocates raw memory. The result is a real live object created in that memory. If you don't call your function, new is getting called regular.

Answer (score 0):

`operator new` is called by `operator new[]`

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_opv.cc#L32